# sql dump file.. load to mysql

Tags: python, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

Ok first, please assume that this is the first time I will be writing a single alphabet of code in SQL.. so please please please... it would be very kind if you can explain me each step. :)
I am using mac for this development.
So in the desktop, I have a huge (1.5GB) dumpfile of a database.
I have mysqlworkbench (yes I have never worked in that either :( )
And I have installed MySQLdb.
So, basically what I want to do is use the data in the database from python.
So I have python.. mysqldb to connect to db.. huge db and mysqlworkbench..
Now I assume, that this dumpfile is useless as its not in form of database..
so how do I "mount" this dump to a database..(mysqlworkbench)
After that how do I query from python..
(like the port number.. username , password!! ? )
It would be of huge help if anyone can help me.. I have been stuck in this since morning.. :(

Comment: How does the file start out? (this is so you can clarify what you mean, since you are new to SQL).

Comment: (since comments cannot be edited after 5 mins, I ask again an edited question)... How does the file start out? (this is so you can clarify what you mean, since (I am assuming) you are new to SQL). You can do this by typing "head <filename>". Does it start with "CREATE DATABASE"?

Comment: Hi.. head <filename> gives the following results.. MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.53, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: king-prod-trkdb01    Database: king_tracking
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.1.53-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

Comment: Umm.. also whenever I try to create a database.. in mysql.. I get this error:  ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'testdb' (errno: 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the data in the file, it needs to be imported into the database. (Think of the file as a recipe for MySQL to make a database. Now you need to tell MySQL to make the database from the recipe).

You can import the database using command line, a python script or even MySQL workbench. However, due to the size of the file, using MySQL workbench could be a problem (Note: I am not familiar with MySQL workbench).

To import the database with the command line use the command:

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h localhost king_tracking < <filename>
```

---

To actually use the database with python, there are several step by step tutorials available, easily accessible from a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20mysql%20tutorial). A basic script is ([from here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html))

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                       user = "testuser",
                       passwd = "testpass",
                       db = "test")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
row = cursor.fetchone ()
print "server version:", row[0]
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()
```

This just shows the version of MySQL, however if

```
"SELECT VERSION()"
```

is replaced by your own query, like

```
"SELECT * FROM <tablename> LIMIT 0,30"
```

you can execute your own queries.

In order to understand the tutorials on interfacing python and MySQL, you should be familiar with both separately. A good [SQL tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20tutorial) is [the one at W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

---

The  problem with creating a table is separate from the original question, but may need to be addressed before trying to import the file into the database.